# Test coverage for a user trigger: How to prevent "DML not allowed on User" in test-class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, user, dml, test-data-isolation

I want to deploy a trigger on user. Therefore I need > 1% coverage on the trigger. To invoke the trigger in my test class, I've tried this:

```
@isTest public class elfTriggerFrameworkTest {
  public static testMethod void testObject() {
    User u = new User();
    u.Email                                                 = 'test123z@elastify.eu';
    u.IsActive                                              = false;
    u.Alias                                                 = 'TT';
    u.CommunityNickname                                     = 'test';
    u.UserName                                              = 'test123z@elastify.eu';
    u.LastName                                              = 'test';
    u.ProfileId                                             = elfTriggerFrameworkLib.getAdminProfileId();
    u.EmailEncodingKey                                      = 'ISO-8859-1';
    u.EmailPreferencesAutoBcc                               = true;
    u.EmailPreferencesAutoBccStayInTouch                    = false;
    u.EmailPreferencesStayInTouchReminder                   = false;
    u.LanguageLocaleKey                                     = 'en_US';
    u.LocaleSidKey                                          = 'de_DE_EURO';
    u.TimeZoneSidKey                                        = 'Europe/Berlin';
    u.UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin                    = false;
    // lot of other fields irrelevant for this question removed ...
    upsert u;   
  }
}
```

As an unfortunate, this only gives you a strange error when you try to save the testClass

```
DML not allowed on User
```

How to get rid of that error in order to get the enforced test coverage on that trigger?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why, but all you need is to change

```
upsert u;
```

into

```
insert u;
update u;
```

and all the pain goes away. You can save without any problem and the coverage is there.

I found this solution here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091B5IAI - but as it is so unreadable, not easily found by searching and buried in the last answer after a lot of misleading stuff, I think it's worth to point it out for others running into the same error.

Actually I found myself using always `upsert` instead of `insert` - this might be a bad habit...

Comment: Definitely you should only upsert if you have a concrete reason to do so...

Comment: I do inserts on all my tests and never had that issue. That is definitely a strange problem.